# In symfony2, why AppKernel Instantiated twice?

Tags: php, symfony

I use symfony2. In AppKernel.php, I writed like this:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel {

    public function __construct ($environment, $debug) {
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
        echo "ok";
    }
}
```

in the page, it shows "ok" once in prod environment, but shows twice in dev environment. it seems the AppKernel is instantiated twice? I don't know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dev environment, symfony2 provides the "web debug toolbar", which is loaded asynchronouly. This means that a second kernel is booted to load the bar.

Comment: Thank you. but I have closed "web debug toolbar". Is that in app/config/config_dev.yml? `web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false`